# Ember Test: Acceptance Test passes in Chrome, but fails in Safari and PhantomJS

Tags: ember.js, phantomjs

I am testing a form field where I allow my users to edit their phone number. They can click an edit button and start editing their new number. However, if they click cancel (as opposed to save), the form would discard the change and show the original phone number.

```
test('I cancel editing phone number', function(assert){
  visit('/onboarding/vehicle-approval');
  click(editButton);
  fillIn('.edit-phone-field input', '9991234567');
  click(cancelButton);

  andThen(function() {
    assert.equal(currentURL(), '/onboarding/vehicle-approval');
    assert.equal(find('.edit-phone-field input').val(), user[0].phoneNumber);
  });
});
```

My test passes in Chrome, but fails in Safari and PhantomJS. It fails at the assertion: `assert.equal(find('.edit-phone-field input').val(), user[0].phoneNumber);` because we expect the value to be the old phone number, but the new phone number (`9991234567`) is what we are actually getting.

I've tried some of the other answers, like updating phantomJS to 2.0, but none of them have worked for me so far.

Why is my test passing on Chrome, but failing on the other browsers?

Comment: Does the cancel function work as intended in Safari in manual mode? Maybe there are errors?

Comment: @Vaviloff I tested it in both Safari and Chrome. The cancel function works as intended when I manually test them. Initially I thought it was an issue with my cancel function, but now I think it might be a testing configuration issue since the test passes in the Chrome case.

Comment: `return pauseTest()` is your friend for debugging things like this. Also, you [can attach to the phantomjs debugging outlet](http://www.cssugared.com/2015/03/23/debugging-phantomjs-with-ember-cli-and-testem/) to inspect the DOM.

Comment: @steveax Yes, i've tried using return pauseTest() before my assertions. My value in the input field shows the old number (which is expected), but the assertion still fails.

Comment: Testing Heisenbugs are the worst. What does the cancel action look like? What is the `document.activeElement` before the assertions? I've had some luck with putting clicks inside `Ember.run` function blocks on finicky tests.